# Mobile: differentiating device-shake and touch-shake with sensible names

Tags: mobile, input

With mobile devices, there are (at least) 2 kinds of user actions that could be called "shake"

1. Shaking the device itself
2. Shaking some draggable item (à la Windows 7 shake-to-minimize-other-windows)

I can't come up with any sensible names to differentiate these two actions. Does anybody know of reasonable terms for these actions?

Comment: How common is shaking some draggable item? What real-world action corresponds to this metaphor?

Comment: I don't know that there's a direct real-world action that corresponds well, but after seeing it used in Windows, it got me curious as to how it might work on a mobile platform. IMO it's a garbage feature on the desktop, but it strikes me as a potential alternative for some of the awkward or unintuitive mobile gestures I see in abundance (triple tap, multi-finger swipe, combinations of short/long press).

Comment: That's my point: don't clog your mind with uncommon, strange, confusing interactions.

Comment: It doesn't seem as obviously as bad as the common gestures I see elsewhere, at least worth exploring in a few contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Jiggle seems like the word that an interface would use to describe shaking a dragable item. According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jiggle), jiggle means

1. *noun* - a slight irregular shaking motion
2. *verb* - move to and fro